# Puppet fails on icinga2 using puppet-icinga2 module

Tags: puppet, icinga2

I am trying to bring up a box for icinga2 using vagrant and 
I am using puppet-icinga2 from https://github.com/Icinga/puppet-icinga2/tree/v0.6.2

so I have a role as shown below

```
class role::icinga2_server {

class { 'postgresql::server':
      ip_mask_deny_postgres_user => '0.0.0.0/32',
      ip_mask_allow_all_users    => '0.0.0.0/0',
      listen_addresses           => 'localhost',
      postgres_password          => 'password',}

postgresql::server::db {
        'icinga2_data':
        user => 'icinga2',
        password => 'password'
}



class { 'icinga2::server':
      server_db_type => 'pgsql',
      db_host => 'localhost',
      db_port => '5432',
      db_name => 'icinga2_data',
      db_user => 'icinga2',
      db_password => 'password',
 }
}
```

So when I provision box I get postgres intall fine via puppet (using puppet-postgres module) then puppet throws errors on

```
==> centos7: Notice: /Stage[main]/Vagrant/Group[vagrant]/gid: gid changed '1000' to '500'
==> centos7: Debug: /Stage[main]/Vagrant/Group[vagrant]: The container Class[Vagrant] will propagate my refresh event
==> centos7: Debug: Exec[postgres_schema_load](provider=posix): Executing 'su - postgres -c 'export PGPASSWORD='\''password'\'' && psql -U icinga2 -h localhost -d icinga2_data < /usr/share/icinga2-ido-pgsql/schema/pgsql.sql' && export PGPASSWORD='' && touch /etc/icinga2/postgres_schema_loaded.txt'
==> centos7: Debug: Executing 'su - postgres -c 'export PGPASSWORD='\''password'\'' && psql -U icinga2 -h localhost -d icinga2_data < /usr/share/icinga2-ido-pgsql/schema/pgsql.sql' && export PGPASSWORD='' && touch /etc/icinga2/postgres_schema_loaded.txt'
==> centos7: Notice: /Stage[main]/Icinga2::Server::Install::Execs/Exec[postgres_schema_load]/returns: psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
==> centos7: Notice: /Stage[main]/Icinga2::Server::Install::Execs/Exec[postgres_schema_load]/returns:   Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
==> centos7: Notice: /Stage[main]/Icinga2::Server::Install::Execs/Exec[postgres_schema_load]/returns:   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
==> centos7: Notice: /Stage[main]/Icinga2::Server::Install::Execs/Exec[postgres_schema_load]/returns: could not connect to server: Connection refused
==> centos7: Notice: /Stage[main]/Icinga2::Server::Install::Execs/Exec[postgres_schema_load]/returns:   Is the server running on host "localhost" (192.168.10.131) and accepting
==> centos7: Notice: /Stage[main]/Icinga2::Server::Install::Execs/Exec[postgres_schema_load]/returns:   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
==> centos7: Error: su - postgres -c 'export PGPASSWORD='\''password'\'' && psql -U icinga2 -h localhost -d icinga2_data < /usr/share/icinga2-ido-pgsql/schema/pgsql.sql' && export PGPASSWORD='' && touch /etc/icinga2/postgres_schema_loaded.txt returned 2 instead of one of [0]
```

I see errors stating psql cannot connect but when I bring my vagrant box up, ssh in I see postgres installed running and listening fine. I can also connect using psql but puppet fails at creating schema on postgres as seen on debug output.

I also did login and executed same command for postgres schema load and it did work fine.

Why puppet is failing to load schema?

Comment: Have you tried manually running the command that's erroring and looking for a more detailed message?

Comment: I have tried that, logged in and executed `su - postgres -c 'export PGPASSWORD='\''password'\'' && psql -U icinga2 -h localhost -d icinga2_data < /usr/share/icinga2-ido-pgsql/schema/pgsql.sql' && export PGPASSWORD='' && touch /etc/icinga2/postgres_schema_loaded.txt` and it did work as expected

Answer (score -1):

The release versions of that module are really really old, and not very good either.

You should start by trying out our current development state, currently still in a branch called "develop".

There are still some things todo until we reach a releasable state (in terms of cleanup and breaking changes).

You should have a look on the [roadmap](https://dev.icinga.org/projects/puppet-icinga2/roadmap).